# Save a message to a text file with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I use the following code to detect an "enter" key and send the value of a text input to a php page:

```
$(document).ready(LoadMe);

function LoadMe()
{


$('#test').bind('keypress', function(e){
   var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
   if(code == 13) // Enter key is pressed
   {
        var theval = $(this).val();
        var sessName = '<?php echo $_SESSION['username']?>';
        //alert(theval);
        $('<p>'+sessName+': '+theval+'</p>').appendTo('#content');
   }
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "savechat.php?msg="+theval,
                //data: { value : theval },
                success: function(data)
                {
                    //alert("success!");
                }
            });
});
}
```

savechat.php

```
// echo $_GET['msg'];
    $file = 'people.txt';
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    $current .= $_GET['msg']."\n";
    file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

html:

```
<input id="test" type="text" >
<div id="content"> </div>
```

Event though the code is a bit cluttered it works but the txt file gets updated with a lot of undefined lines:

```
undefined
undefined
1
undefined
12
undefined
123
1234
undefined
123456
1234566
12345667
123456678
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
r
```

Thanks for your valuable feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're triggering the ajax event if it is not code 13 (= Enter).

`theval` is only defined **if** it you hit enter (code 13) - otherwise it is `undefined`;-). Change that to:

```
$(document).ready(LoadMe);

function LoadMe()
{
    $('#test').bind('keypress', function(e){
        var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        if(code == 13) // Enter key is pressed
        {
            var theval = $(this).val();
            var sessName = '<?php echo $_SESSION['username']?>';
            //alert(theval);
            $('<p>'+sessName+': '+theval+'</p>').appendTo('#content');

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "savechat.php?msg="+theval,
                //data: { value : theval },
                success: function(data)
                {
                    //alert("success!");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

and it should work fine ;-)) - Although untested...

Answer (score 1):

Try your ajax code in `enter key` like

```
if(code == 13) // Enter key is pressed
{
    var theval = $(this).val();
    var sessName = '<?php echo $_SESSION['username']?>';
    //alert(theval);
    $('<p>'+sessName+': '+theval+'</p>').appendTo('#content');   
    $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "savechat.php?msg="+theval,
         //data: { value : theval },
         success: function(data)
         {
              //alert("success!");
         }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

$(document).ready(LoadMe);

function LoadMe()
   {
       $('#test').bind('keypress', function(e){
       var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        if(code == 13) // Enter key is pressed
    {
        var theval = $(this).val();
        var sessName = '<?php echo $_SESSION['username']?>';
        //alert(theval);
        $('<p>'+sessName+': '+theval+'</p>').appendTo('#content');

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "savechat.php?msg="+theval,
            //data: { value : theval },
            success: function(data)
            {
               alert("success");
            }
        });
    }
   });
 }
```